# Returns an error and does not delete the entry

Tags: php

Returns an error and does not delete the entry, what could be the problem?

```
  public function del(){
      echo "<h1>DEL</h1> method of ".get_class($this);
      $params = explode("?", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);  
      $params = $params[1]; 
      parse_str($params, $arr);
      vd($arr);
      $mysqli = new \mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "quest"); 
      $mysqli -> query ("DELETE FROM users WHERE id = '{$arr["id"]}'");
    }
```

Comment: you should post error also

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Without the error not possible to help you out

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /home/cabox/workspace/core/NewsController.class.php on line 22

Notice: Undefined index: id in /home/cabox/workspace/core/NewsController.class.php on line 26

Comment: @MegaRoks `id = '{$arr["id"]}'` won't work within strings. Should be `id = '{$arr[id]}'`. Also, not a good practice to use user input without sanitizing. @Stony's answer should work fine for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have an syntax error in your delete line:

```
$mysqli->query(sprintf("DELETE FROM users WHERE id = %d", $arr["id"]));
```

you quotes are not correct. Normally you should use prepared statements but to get your code work you can use `sprintf` and be sure that you have a number in your delete statement.

Comment: I changed the request to suggested, when typing in the address bar it does not delete the entry with id 18, but gives an error. Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Error! Warning! Achtung! Danger! in /home/cabox/workspace/core/FactoryRouting.class.php:35 Stack trace: #0 /home/cabox/workspace/index.php(32): core\FactoryRouting::getController('/news/del&id=18') #1 {main} thrown in /home/cabox/workspace/core/FactoryRouting.class.php on line 35